# Are blaze-lib's elementwise operations automagically parallel?

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing

blaze-lib (https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib) has element-wise operations.

Specifically, I am interested in logarithm ([bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze/wiki/Vector%20Operations#!log-log2-log10)).

If I compile my program that uses blaze-lib and enable OpenMP, will the element-wise operations automatically uses more than one cpu core?

Comment: Not sure if it has the answer, but this is a good talk about the library: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/CPP/CppCon-2016/CppCon-2016-Klaus-Iglberger-The-Blaze-High-Performance-Math-Library

Answer (score 0):

Yes. they are automatically parallel.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer.